# jQuery - Get all html in between some tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to scrape a website which looks like this:

```
<p></p>

<!-- I want to get HTML from here... -->

<h2> </h2>
<table> </table>

<h2> </h2>
<table> </table>

<h2> </h2>
<table> </table>

<!-- to here -->

<div> </div>

<h2> </h2>
<table> </table>
```

As annotated above, I want to get all the HTML between `<p>` and the `<div>`. I don't want the `<h2>` and `<table>` below the div.

Is there a good way to scrape those parts? If possible, I want to avoid targeting child index.

Thanks

Comment: You can wrap all the html tags that you want to scrap in one DIV and then easily can scrap.

Comment: @HarshSanghani Unfortunately, I can't edit the HTML in that site

Comment: solved your issue using others answer?

Comment: @HarshSanghani yep, never thought it would be that simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$('p').nextUntil('div').addClass('add')
```

```css
.add{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>

<!-- I want to get HTML from here... -->

<h2> I want to get HTML from here...</h2>
<table><tr><td>I want to get HTML from here...</td></tr> </table>

<h2> I want to get HTML from here...</h2>
<table><tr><td>I want to get HTML from here...</td></tr> </table>

<h2> I want to get HTML from here...</h2>
<table><tr><td>I want to get HTML from here...</td></tr> </table>

<!-- to here -->

<div> </div>

<h2> </h2>
<table> </table>
```

Use [.nextUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

> Get all following siblings of each element up to but not including the element matched by the selector, DOM node, or jQuery object passed.

Comment: Nice, never knew this function exists in jQuery

Answer (score 3):

Use `.nextUntil()` to get all next element from specific element to any particular element.

```js
console.log($("p:first").nextUntil("div"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>

<!-- I want to get HTML from here... -->

<h2> </h2>
<table> </table>

<h2> </h2>
<table> </table>

<h2> </h2>
<table> </table>

<!-- to here -->

<div> </div>

<h2> </h2>
<table> </table>
```